# How to find/calculate daily S&P500 dividends?

Tags: equities, data, dividends, sp500

I need a time series with daily dividend data on the S&P500. I understand most dividend data is on a quarterly basis but I'm looking to model short-term effects of COVID-19 on dividends so I need a daily/weekly frequency. **Does anyone have any ideas?**

Is is possible to use the S&P500 price and total return indexes to calculate daily dividend? And if so, how do you do this? I have tried something like this but then I get stuck with a static 252-trading day moving average.

Note; interpolating quarterly data to a daily frequency is sadly not an option.

Comment: There are many services that keep track of dividend payments (dates and amounts for a large number of stocks). Unfortunately I don't know any free ones (the one that I know costs 150).

Comment: I assume you have already looked at this https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/36440/dividend-yields-of-the-sp500 but it wasn't helpful for some reason (I did not understand your remark about 252 day moving average).

Answer (score 1):

I would use the difference between simple return (price change) and total return gross of dividend withholding tax.

Comment: This might be a good starting point but I wonder if the numbers to be calculated using these two series would be useful enough as S&P 500 price index is also adjusted for special dividends.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to estimate what would happen if there were daily dividends?

If so you could try:

1. Find the geometric $g$ rate of all quarterly $D$
2. Convert the quarterly $g$ rate into daily,
3. Find starting day $D_{0}$ and from there calculate $D(1+g)$... till you’ve found all wanted daily dividend streams

This would be how I’d attempt to find it.
This is weird tho... dividends aren’t always paid, especially not daily.

Comment: Thanks for the edits